# How can I have my netty client detect if my netty server listens on a port (is available)?

Tags: java, netty

I have a netty client that works fine if the server application is listening. But if the server application is not running and therefore not listening on the port, the client still runs as if it expects the server to be there.

I would like to handle the case when the server is not listening and in such a case not even send the data (and do something else instead, like telling the user to contact an admin or so). Is this even possible?

Note:
If the client attempts to connect to an unspecified port or ip, my client throws exceptions which I can handle. My issue is that no exceptions are thrown when the server is not listening on the port it should normally listen to.

Comment: You can use [URLConnection.setConnectionTimeout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout-int-) to try a connection.

Comment: But then I'd have to wait until that timeout is over. I could also just wait until the client is done anyway and check if an result was received, and if not handle that case. But I'd prefer a way to find out what's up with my server rather than waiting for a timeout or the client to finish. Also: What would happen if my connection was slow for some reason? Wouldn't the timeout abort the connection in that case?

Comment: A kind of `ping` that is. For localhost one could try to bind the port to oneself (checking that the port is in free), but that is a terrible hack. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeap. Sometimes you can't detect that server is down/not listening on port anymore.

So for that case, you may add to your client pipeline `ReadTimeoutHandler`. Which will throw `ReadTimeoutException` in case your client didn't get any message from the server within the certain period of time.
However, this may be not enough. For example, when your connection between server and client is not very active this exception could be thrown too. So for that case, you may need to implement ping-pong handlers, that will tell for your `ReadTimeoutHandler` that connection is active and it will not throw the exception in that case.

Comment: The "PingPong Handler" concept seems to work for my problem. After some googling I tried the code from this example  https://gist.github.com/Topher-the-Geek/6729681#file-pingpongserverhandler-java